# Using undeclared generics to force a type distinction

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, .net-5

I'm currently trying to create a poll/survey program and I'm trying to use generics to keep things flexible. In my implementation, I'm trying to link together `IPollQuestion<TAnswer>` questions using `IPollQuestionLink<TPreviousAnswer, TNextAnswer>` links to show a possible flow from one question to another.

A text example could be:

1. Are you older than 18? (TAnswer = bool)
2. Do you drink alcohol? (TAnswer = bool)
3. How many alcoholic beverages do you drink per week? (TAnswer = int)

In which case the link between Q1 and Q2 should be `TPreviousAnswer is bool` and `TNextAnswer is bool` whereas the link between Q2 and Q3 should be `TPreviousAnswer is bool` and `TNextAnswer is int`.

The link between questions seemed pretty straightforward to write:

```cs
public interface IPollQuestionLink<TPreviousAnswer, TNextAnswer>
{
    IPollQuestion<TPreviousAnswer> PreviousQuestion { get; set; }
    IPollQuestion<TNextAnswer> NextQuestion { get; set; }
    Func<TPreviousAnswer, bool> Check { get; set; } // Check if NextQuestion should be asked
}
```

But when I write the question interface itself, I get stuck in specifying that the `TAnswer` type to a question can be different to the answer type of a follow-up question, as with the link between Q2 and Q3 in the text example above.

```cs
public interface IPollQuestion<TAnswer>
{
    TAnswer Answer { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IPollQuestionLink<TAnswer, /* Causes problems */>> NextQuestionLinks { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this or will I have to use a different strategy to create this polling system?

Comment: Have you considered having an `IPollQuestion` interface with no type parameter, which `IPollQuestion<TAnswer>` then inherits from? Often (In my experience), if generics are fighting you, you should be looking to use them less, not more.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'll give that a shot, I'm not sure what the `IPollQuestionLink` interface would have to look like then

Comment: It strikes me than nothing in the `Link` really needs to know the type of the next answer, and that was the type you seemed to be struggling to supply, so next answer would by `IPollQuestion`, not `IPollQuestion<TAnswer>`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that to work on a small example to see if it works.

Comment: The whole premise of generics is that the types are known at compile time.  Unless your questions are all static (which seems unlikely; I would assume post poll software would be designed to have polls designed at runtime) generics seems like a poor fit in general.

Comment: @Servy are you suggesting a more general graph/network approach then? Where the types are omitted and only the `Check` is considered from external inputs?

Comment: @JansthcirlU I would probably expect a `Type` of the type of the poll question probably, or an enum if you only support a small finite list of types.